# Attaching file to Contact Form 7 E-Mail

Tags: wordpress

I'm working in WordPress with Contact Form 7. I'm dynamically creating a .txt file based on the users submitted data, and I want to attach that file to the e-mail that the user is sent from Contact Form 7.

To confirm, the file is created and saved in the correct location. My issue is definitely with attaching it to the e-mail from CF7.

this worked until cf7 version 7.5.3.2, after this version add_uploaded_file become private function and file stopped attaching.

Here is my example (worked before cf7 upgraded to version 7.5.4 and above):

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_sender' );
 function CF7_pre_sender($cf7) {    
        $formid = $_POST['_wpcf7'];
 global $date_stamp;
 if($formid === '4436'):
            $output = "";
            $output .= $_POST['your-message'] . '|' . $_POST['your-address']  . '|||' . $_POST['your-city']  . '||' . $_POST['your-post-code'] . '||' . $_POST['your-name'] . '|' . $_POST['your-name'] . '||' . $_POST['your-email'] . '||' . $_POST['your-telephone'] . '|' . $_POST['your-telephone'] . '||True|True||' . $_POST['model'] . '||' . $_POST['SN'] . '|2020-10-17T12:00:00.000Z||' . $date_stamp . '|' ;  
 file_put_contents(ABSPATH. $date_stamp . ".txt",  $output);
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            $submission->add_uploaded_file('myfile', ABSPATH. $date_stamp . ".txt");
 endif;
 };
```

Everything works up until: $submission->add_uploaded_file('myfile', ABSPATH. $date_stamp . ".txt");
File is created on the server side but it is not attached to email

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

I expect to attach a file to email.

Answer (score 0):

Since the add_uploaded_file() function became a private function, you will probably need to use a different method to attach a file to the email. Like adding it to the `$attachments` array in the `$mail`.

try the below;

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_sender' );

function CF7_pre_sender($cf7) {
    $formid = $_POST['_wpcf7'];

    if($formid === '4436'){
        $output = "";
        $output .= $_POST['your-message'] . '|' . $_POST['your-address']  . '|||' . $_POST['your-city']  . '||' . $_POST['your-post-code'] . '||' . $_POST['your-name'] . '|' . $_POST['your-name'] . '||' . $_POST['your-email'] . '||' . $_POST['your-telephone'] . '|' . $_POST['your-telephone'] . '||True|True||' . $_POST['model'] . '||' . $_POST['SN'] . '|2020-10-17T12:00:00.000Z||' . $date_stamp . '|' ;

        $file_path = ABSPATH . $date_stamp . ".txt";

        file_put_contents($file_path, $output);

        $mail = $cf7->prop('mail');

        $attachments = array($file_path);

        $mail['attachments'] = $attachments;

        $cf7->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried it - email is sent but no attachment in email.

Comment: check to see if the `$file_path` is correct. maybe you can echo it and see if it is right.